# Is there any observational evidence for dark matter vortices?

Tags: observational-astronomy, dark-matter

The paper here "Vortices and waves in light dark matter" https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.01188
says that in dark matter halos vortices arise. In a vortex some particles move faster than others - the velocity depends on 1/r according to the paper.
This should lead to an uneven relativistic mass increase increase. Is this enough to bend light from stars as it approaches the Earth so telescopes detect it?

Comment: Because particles closer to the centre of the vortex move faster and  so would increase their mass more under special relativity.

Comment: @Rory Alsop I have reworded the question because you were right about it being unclear what I meant.

Comment: I found out from one of the authors of the paper that the vortices need a telescope resolution of 10^-10 arcsecs to detect light bending and even Gaia satellite only has 10^-6 arcsecs .